# Iterates and square the odd numbers less than 30 with class in c++

Tags: c++, class

I'm working on a C++ program which iterates through numbers less than 30 and finds out the odd numbers among then square it.
I am required to use class function in the program but my output was a list of '0'. I am not sure whether I am having issues in declaring my constructors that gives me such output.

So my code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Square // class to square integers
{
    private:
    int x;

    public:
    Square()//no argument constructor
    {
        x = 0;
    }

    Square(int num)//constructor with argument
    {
        x = num;
    }

    int square()//member function with no argument
    {
        return x;
    }
    int square(int num)// member function with argument
    {
        x *= num;

        return x * x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //int x = 0;
    Square odd;

    cout << "This program iterates through the odd numbers less than 30." << endl;
    cout << "The program will output the Square of the numbers." << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
    {
        if (x % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << odd.square() << endl;
        }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing `Square` to its default value of `0`. You need to do this

```
Square odd;

for (int i = 1; i < 30; i += 2) {
  Square odd(i);
  cout << odd.square(1) << endl;
}
```

Comment: expected output to look like this: 
1  9  25  49  81  121  169  225  289  361 441 529 625  729  841
but it gave a whole lotta large numbers @@

Comment: it squares up the squared number :/

Comment: When I run this I'm getting the correct answer. Check it out [here](https://repl.it/EJRg).